# Application for Schengen visa(France)

Tags: schengen-visas

I'm a college student aged 20 from Kenya, East Africa. I tend to travel to France at the end of September to Paris for one week. The trip is to be sponsored by my cousin who's quite financially stable.

Apart from his bank statement, cover letter stating that he's sponsoring everything and employment contract, what other documents should I bring from him?

Do I also need to have a bank statement considering that I'm just a student with no income?

I know that I have to have a medical insurance, travel itinerary for my one week stay in Paris, cover letter from my college, return air ticket and hostel accommodation (I tend to supply the embassy with a dummy air ticket and hostel reservation, is that okay?) what other documents should I bring to boost my chances of getting the visa?

I have a good travel resume as I have travelled to 2 east African countries (hope that will help) but this will be my first time traveling overseas.

Kindly suggest to me what other documents that would help boost my chances of getting a visa and any other information that I need to have, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'dummy air ticket and hostel reservation', but under no circumstances should you submit fake documents. If you intend to use an agency that specialises in providing real confirmations for visa applications which are then cancelled, you should assume that the visa officers will recognise your documents for what they are. I can't say what weight they will give such documents.

Comment: Not providing your bank statements is not an option. Even if you're a student "with no income", presumably you still need to eat, and thus pay someone for food and for having somewhere to sleep. The consulate will want to see documentation for how you make that happen -- otherwise they'll default to assuming that you starve, and are therefore desperate to go to Europe and look for (illegal) work to keep yourself alive with.

Comment: The embassy state that you can use air ticket reservation and pay later for the air ticket once you've gotten your visa application approved, that is why I'm looking forward to getting real confirmations from a travel agency and obviously my sponsor will have enough funds to prove that we can afford a return ticket and all that stuff.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ig I'll need to build a 3 month bank statement as that's what they state, I generally pay for most of stuff using mobile banking and sometimes by cash so gotta change my ways starting from next month